# array[] stores > char, how to use it

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    char array[2];
    printf("Enter two of < or > or =");
    scanf("%s",array);
    if ((2 array[0] 3)&&(4 array[1] 3)){
        printf("It works\n");
    }
    else printf("Yup! the code still works\n");

}
```

The above simplified code is meant to take input <> from the user and tries to use it to compare between two numbers but the compiler throws an error 'cause it is not accepting array[0] as >. please provide a solution to the problem.

Comment: `(2 array[0] 3)` is invalid syntax.  What you expect this to do?

Comment: @dbush Treat the data in the array (the character `'<'` or `'>'`) as an operator (`<` or `>`) at runtime.

Comment: Oh, I see. You're getting the user to enter the comparison symbol.  try something like this:  if ( array[0] == '<') { if ( 2 < 3 ) printf("yup0") }   You can't make the operator a variable, but you can use a different operator based on a variable

Comment: @dbush I want to take a string of > as input store it in an array and then use it to compare two numbers

Comment: stop pushing forward, restart learning but this time don't skip anything.

Comment: @Kieveli yes that is a valid solution but is there any way to convert the char stored into the operator, cause I think your process will decrease the time efficient as I have to take about 10^5 INPUTS

Comment: No, because compiled code is known before hand.  Operators are compiled necessarily part of the compiled code.  At runtime, the code does not have dynamic operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just use a char as an operator, but you can use an if else sequence based on the input to compare the values.

Ex

```
if (array[0] = '>') some_variable = 2>3;
else if (array[0] = '<') some_variable = 3>2;
else if (array[0] = '=') some_variable = 3==2;
```

You could also use a switch statement if you prefer.

You could then repeat a similar sequence for the second element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a char variable as a replacement for an operator. You must compare the variable with a specific char and return the comparison.

```
int num1;
int num2;
bool comp[2];
switch(array[0]) {
case '>':
    comp[0] = (num1 > num2);
    printf("%a > %b\n", num1, num2);
    break;
case '<':
    comp[0] = (num1 < num2);
    printf("%a < %b\n", num1, num2);
    break;
case '=':
    comp[0] = (num1 == num2);
    printf("%a = %b\n", num1, num2);
    break;
default:
    comp[0] = false;
    printf("Invalid character %c\n", array[0]);
    break;
}
switch(array[1]) {
... //Switch over the other element of array
}
if(comp[0] && comp[1]) {
    printf("It works\n");
}
```

If you wish to replace an operator with a word, you can use a macro:

```
#define LT <
bool x = (1 LT 0); //Sets x to false
```